# (re)start python script with applescript

Tags: python, shell, applescript, restart

I have a Python script that runs in an infinite loop (it's a server).

I want to write an AppleScript that will start this script if it isn't started yet, and otherwise force-quit and restart it. This will make it easy for me to make changes to the server code while programming.

Currently I only know how to start it: `do shell script "python server.py"`

Comment: This is too broad. Please include the script, what server, and what you have done so far.

Comment: The content of the python script really doesn't matter. It's an infinite loop, that's all applescript needs to know. Also, I did write what I have done so far: 'do shell script "python server.py"' is an applescript that starts the server. I need to know how to close it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that AppleScript's `do shell script` starts the shell (`/bin/sh`) in the *root* directory (`/`) by default, so you should specify an explicit path to `server.py`

In the following examples I'll assume directory path `~/srv`.

Here's the shell command:

```
pid=$(pgrep -fx 'python .*/server\.py'); [ "$pid" ] && kill -9 $pid; python ~/srv/server.py
```

As an AppleScript statement, wrapped in `do shell script` - note the `\`-escaped inner `"` and `\` chars.:

```
do shell script "pid=$(pgrep -fx 'python .*/server\\.py'); [ \"$pid\" ] && kill -9 $pid; python ~/srv/server.py"
```

- `pgrep -fx '^python .*/server\.py$'` uses `pgrep` to find your running command by *regex* against the full command line (`-f`), requiring a full match (`-x`), and returns the PID (process ID), if any.

  - Note that I've used a more abstract regex to underscore the fact that `pgrep` (always) treats its search term as a *regular expression*.
    To specify the full launch command line as the regex, use `python ~/srv/server\.py` - note the `\`-escaping of `.` for full robustness.
- `[ "$pid" ] && kill -9 $pid` kills the process, *if* a PID was found (`[ "$pid" ]` is short for `[ -n "$pid" ]` and evaluates to true only if `$pid` is nonempty); `-9` sends signal `SIGKILL`, which forcefully terminates the process.
- `python ~/srv/server.py` then (re)starts your server.

Answer (score 1):

On the shell, if you do `ps aux | grep python\ server.py | head -n1`, you'll get the ID of the process running `server.py`. You can then use `kill -9` to kill that process and restart it:

```
kill -9 `ps aux | grep python\ server.py | head -n1 | python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().split()[1])'`
```

That'll kill it. Al you have to do now is to restart it:

```
python server.py
```

You can combine the two with `&&`:

```
kill -9 `ps aux | grep python\ server.py | head -n1 | python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().split()[1])'` && python server.py
```

Of course, you already know how to put that in a `do shell script`!

Comment: Looks like it almost works, but I get an error: "sh: line 0: kill: socks python\\ /Volumes/path/server.py | head -n1 | python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().split()[1])': arguments must be process or job IDs"

Comment: My script was: do shell script "kill -9 \"socks python\\ /Volumes/path/server.py | head -n1 | python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().split()[1])'\" && python /Volumes/path/server.py"

Comment: @FlorianDietz: Sorry, I used an alias that doesn't exist on your computer. Check out the edit. Also, you'll need to change your script to `grep server.py` instead of the full path of `server.py`

Comment: I am getting the same error for: do shell script "kill -9 \"ps aux python\\ grep server.py | head -n1 | python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().split()[1])'\" && python /Volumes/path/server.py"

Comment: @FlorianDietz: check out the edit. It's `ps aux | grep python`, not `ps aux python\\ grep`. Sorry - I hadn't properly replaced my aliasing before

Comment: I was looking at the second line, which you did not update yet. I still get the same error, for: do shell script "kill -9 \"ps aux | grep python\\ server.py | head -n1 | python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().split()[1])'\""
and also if I write 'python' instead of 'python\\'

Comment: @FlorianDietz: note that it's `\`ps aux`, not `"ps aux`. Note the backtick -it's above the TAB key

Comment: thanks, I thought that was just for quoting.You are a great help. Now I'm getting much further, but I still get this error: "sh: line 0: kill: (88495) - No such process". Do I need to name the python script differently?

Comment: @FlorianDietz: are you sure your server's running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129380/discussion-between-florian-dietz-and-inspectorg4dget).

Comment: `ps aux` sorts processes by CPU percentage in descending order. `ps aux | grep python\ server.py` matches not only the running server, but also the `grep` command itself.
If `grep` happens to be busier than the server (which is not unlikely), applying `| head -n 1` only returns the `grep` process' PID, and `kill` then not only doesn't kill the server,
but fails with an error message, because the `grep` process no longer exists at that point. As an aside: using Python to extract the 2nd field from the `ps` output is a bit heavy-handed; `… | awk '{print $2}'` is both simpler and faster.

Comment: Assuming you modify your `ps … ` pipeline to only return the server's PID: `kill … && python …` will then not start the server if it wasn't already running:
`kill` will fail if the command substitution returns the empty string, and the `&&` clause will therefore not be executed.